# Setup Microsoft Dynamics NAV for a consultancy company

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I've created a firm in Microsoft NAV but I have problems to set it up for a consultancy company. 
But I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, should i create my consultants as Servicearticles? 
I´ve created the various workplaces they can be placed in (our companies costumers) so we can put the consultants in different companies. But is it the right way to go? And if someone would be nice to explain how we can setup timesheets for these consultants that would be awesome!

Best regards three students trying to pass a course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practise is to create your consultants as resources. 
The resources can be attached to userid who is going to enter lines in the timesheet, and the userid that needs to approve the timesheet lines.

For more info regarding the timesheet:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh175155%28v=nav.70%29.aspx

Good luck with passing your course!